# Difference between pointer to array

Tags: c

What is the difference between these two pointers? Both pointers are pointing to an array? Is it because the first pointer is a pointer to the first element of the array, while the other is a pointer to an array of 5 elements? What differences does this make in code?

```
int arr[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
int *pointer = arr;
int (*pointer2)[5] = arr;
```

Comment: You should be getting a warning for the last: `initialization of 'int (*)[5]' from incompatible pointer type 'int *' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]`

Comment: With `pointer`, the line `int x = pointer[2]` would set `x` to 3. With `pointer2`, the line `int x = pointer2[0][2]` would set `x` to 3. So `pointer2` is not really useful in your example. It would be useful (and wouldn't generate a warning) with an array like `int arr[2][5]`

Comment: @user3386109 what difference does it provide in the last case?

Comment: The difference is a 1D array versus a 2D array.

Answer (score 3):

Your first declaration

```
int *pointer = arr;
```

declares `pointer` as a pointer to a single integer. In the initialization, `arr` decays to a pointer to its first element, so it's equivalent to

```
int *pointer = &arr[0];
```

The second one

```
int (*pointer2)[5] = arr;
```

declares `pointer` as a pointer to an array of 5 integers. The initialization isn't valid, because `arr` decays to a pointer to a single integer, not an array. You'd need to add a cast:

```
int (*pointer2)[5] = (int(*)[5])arr;
```

or take the address of the array (because the decay to pointer doesn't take place when taking the address of the array):

```
int (*pointer)[5] = &arr;
```

The different between the two pointer types becomes apparent when you perform pointer arithmetic, because pointer arithmetic is performed in increments of the size of the type it points to. `pointer+1` is a pointer to `arr[1]`, but `pointer2[1]` would be a pointer to `arr[5]`, which doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks, I showed both (with an explanation).

Answer (score 2):

The second,

```
int (*pointer2)[5] = arr;
```

is an error (constraint violation): initialization with wrong pointer type where there is no implicit conversion. It should be `= &arr`.

Both point to the same place, but have different *types*. This affects not only type checking, but pointer arithmetic and other things. For example, `pointer+1` points to `arr[1]`, but `pointer2+1` points "one past the end" of the object `arr`.

The need for pointer-to-array (rather than just pointer-to-element) types comes up when you work with multi-dimensional arrays. In

```
int matrix[3][3];
```

the name `matrix` alone decays not to a pointer to `matrix[0][0]`, but to a pointer to `matrix[0]` (an array of 3 `int`s representing a "row"). This is what makes multi-dimensional array indexing and pointer arithmetic work.

Comment: So what is the difference in initializing a pointer in these two ways?
scores[3][5] = ...;

int (*pointer)[5] = scores; VS int *pointer = scores;

Comment: @user737163: The latter is invalid for the same reason as the first sentence of my answer. The types do not match. `scores` decays to `int (*)[5]` (pointer to array of 5 `int`s) not `int *`.

Answer (score 2):

The most notorious difference, in terms of usability, is regarding pointer arithmetic, ***i.e.***:

`pointer++` will make the pointer access the second element in the array whereas `pointer2++` will make the pointer access the next block of 5 `int`s. In your code the behavior of this latter case would be [undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior) since you only have one block of 5 ints.

A pointer to array of `SIZE` is useful when handling 2D arrays with `SIZE` columns as you can easily iterate through array lines with this simplified pointer arithmetic.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, variables `pointer` and `pointer2` have different types, however they'll both behave similarly, with the exceptions:

– there will be no *array to pointer decay* occurring for `pointer2` like it does for initial `arr`, i.e.: e.g.:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int arr[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
int *pointer = arr;
int (*pointer2)[5] = &arr;

void func(int *in_arr)
{
   printf("1st: %i, 5th: %i\n", in_arr[0], in_arr[4]);
}

int main(void)
{
    func(pointer);
    func(pointer2); /* generates a warning (in GCC) */
    func(arr);      /* works with no issues*/
}
```

The warning will be:

```
ex.c: In function ‘main’:
ex.c:9:14: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘func’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
    9 |         func(pointer2);
      |              ^~~~~~~~
      |              |
      |              int (*)[5]
ex.c:4:24: note: expected ‘int *’ but argument is of type ‘int (*)[5]’
    4 |         void func(int *in_arr)    {
      |                   ~~~~~^~~~~~
```

– pointer arithmetic will behave differently, `pointer+1` will point at second element, while `pointer2+1` will point after the array `pointer2`.

IMO, the `(type*)[size]` pointers are quite peculiar thing in C. They'll allow, for example, to perform basically a *cast to an array type*, which is a quite strange thing to do in C – normally, you cannot cast anything to an array type (like.: `func( (int [5]) ints_pointer )`, however with *pointer*-type to an array, it's possible to cast to it, so that, e.g.:

```
// same preamble as in previous example…

void func(int (*in_arr)[5]) {
   printf("1st: %i, 5th: %i\n", ((int *)in_arr)[0], 
        ((int *)in_arr)[4]);
}

int main(void) {
    /* ·•Casts•· to a ·•pointer-to-array•· type to mute warnings */
    func( (int(*)[5]) pointer );
    func( (int(*)[5]) arr );
    /* Generates no warning (in GCC) */
    func(pointer2);
}
```

works with no issues.